# Vertical axis overlapping title in excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

How do I fix this my vertical axis is overlapping the axis title as shown below
[image]

Comment: You can try to move the axis title and adjust the size of Chart Area.

Answer (score 2):

Select the plot area, then resize by dragging the left side rightwards.

[image]